# how to debug shipping module / class

Tags: plugins

I'm working on an own shipping module and want to print some arrays.
But, the module is operating in the background, so I can not print the arrays.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add this function to your module

```
function my_print_r( $msg, $name = '' )
{
    $error_dir = '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/debug.log';
    $msg = print_r( $msg, true );
    $log = $name . "  |  " . $msg . "\n";
    error_log( $log, 3, $error_dir );
}
```

And call `my_print_r( $variable_to_inspect, 'description' );`. The file `debug.log` is originally used by [`WP_DEBUG_LOG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG), and if you don't have it enabled only your debug info will be there. This [plugin](https://github.com/brasofilo/view-debug-log) of mine shows the content of that file in the dashboard.